# Reorder *ngFor list and indexes

Tags: angular

I'm facing this issue on my Angular project. I have a simple table with a couple of columns (I just pasted only two columns o make easier to explain).

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th (click)="orderBy()">Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <td>{{ i }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The code above will print a table with a count in the first column. Like this

```
+---+------+
| # | Name | -> onClick() event is here
+---+------+
| 1 | AAAA |
+---+------+
| 2 | BBBB |
+---+------+
| 3 | CCCC |
+---+------+
```

To reorder the list I put a "orderBy()" method on each column. The method is

```
orderBy = () => this.items.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1)
```

When I click on column header, the columns is reordered correctly

```
        +----------- This column is sorted correctly
        |
+---+------+
| # | Name |
+---+------+
| 1 | CCCC |
+---+------+
| 2 | BBBB |
+---+------+
| 3 | AAAA |
+---+------+
  |
  +------------ This column keeps the index counter
```

My question is: **How to reorder the index (first column)?**

The correct result must be this:

```
+---+------+
| # | Name |
+---+------+
| 3 | AAAA |
+---+------+
| 2 | BBBB |
+---+------+
| 1 | CCCC |
+---+------+
  |
  +------------- This column must "follow" the other column new order
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the items model?

Comment: ```items: Array<string> = ['AAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCC']```

Comment: @Michael has the answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `index` in the for rendering, you could introduce a new `id` property for each object of the array. Now each `id` would be bound to the object.

Try the following

Component (Illustration)

```js
 this.items.forEach((item, index) => item.id = index + 1);
```

Template

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th (click)="orderBy()">Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{ item?.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item?.name }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I was considering this option but it could decrease the performance in a long list?

Comment: It would have a hit on performance if the list is long. If possible try to introduce this property in the backend before returning the response. But the `index` variable's state is bound to the `*ngFor` directive. It can't be re-ordered based on the items in the loop.

Comment: Thank you Michael. The backend returns a hash as ID so this is not an option. But I'll accept your answer as correct because you gave me a good idea on how to reorder on frontend. Thanks!